# Issue in creating a function in PostgreSQL using date_trunc

Tags: postgresql

Here is a sample of my code

```
v_sql_main:= ' SELECT min_createdate, max_createdate, createdate, customerid::integer, deviceid::integer, null::bigint as sourceip, null::bigint as sourceip_int, service,  total, end_recordid::bigint '||
 ' FROM ( '||
 ' SELECT min(date_trunc( '||quote_literal('HOUR')||' , firstoccurrence)) as  min_createdate, '||
 '        max(date_trunc( '||quote_literal('HOUR')||' , firstoccurrence)) as  max_createdate, '||
 '        date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' , firstoccurrence) as  createdate,  '||
 '        customerid::integer,  '||
 '        deviceid::integer, '||
 '        service, '||
 case  when v_days < 4 then 
 '        count(1)  as   total '
 else
 '        sum(summcount)  as   total '
 end ||', max(recordid) as end_recordid'
 ' FROM   '|| v_tablename||
 ' LEFT OUTER JOIN '|| v_child_tablename||
 ' ON ' ||v_tablename||'.SERVICE_ID = '|| v_child_tablename||'.SERVICE_ID '||
 '        WHERE  '||
 '             customerid = v_customerid   AND '||
 '             deviceid   = v_deviceid     AND '||
 '             date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' , firstoccurrence) = date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' ,now()- interval '1 day') '||
 ' group by date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' , firstoccurrence),  customerid, deviceid, service ) as a order by total desc limit 10;;';
```

When I try to execute this I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 144: ...unc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' ,now()- interval '1 day') '|...
```

What i need is to get: date-1

Thanks in Advance
SHABEER

Comment: Well that could be a better formatted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
 '             date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' , firstoccurrence) = date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' ,now()- interval '1 day') '||
```

by:

```
'             date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' , firstoccurrence) = date_trunc( '||quote_literal('DAY')||' ,now()- interval '' 1 day'') '||
```

Please take a look to the [Interval syntax documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: ... all of which is much easier to read when you use `EXECUTE ... USING` to supply query parameters, and format identifiers with `format('SELECT ... FROM %I ...', tablename)` etc. Yet everyone keeps on using string concatenation and `quote_literal`.